# Why is the 'time ago' not displayed in my view?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, dashboard

I'm not sure whether this is a bug or not, so I'm just going to ask this. I created a view (and block) with a 'Comment: Post date' field with 'Time ago (with "ago" appended)' as Date format. I didn't fill in a custom date format.

Everything is previewed perfectly, but when I go to my dashboard, I only see the "ago": the actual numbers (hours, minutes, seconds...) aren't displayed.

I cleared caches, but nothing happened. I'm still using the default Seven 7.23 administration theme for my dashboard and I didn't set a custom template file or anything else. I just created the view.

How can I solve this?

**Edit**: I exported my view, so you can read the code [here](http://drupaltesting.weebly.com/time-ago.html).

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? try switching to drupal default theme and try again. Clearing the cache is also a good idea.

Comment: I cleared caches, but nothing happened. I'm still using the default Seven 7.23 administration theme for my dashboard.

Comment: Could you please export that view so I could take a look at it?

Comment: I updated my question and added a link to the code.

Comment: I've imported your view and placed the block on the sidebar of a test installation. It shows the time as it supposed to. I can take a screenshot of it. Did you set any custom template file for that view?

Comment: Here is the screenshot: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2ppaqnd.jpg I have only generated some random content with devel module, unapproved some comments and imported your view. It works.

Comment: That's soo strange! I didn't use a custom template file or anything else. I just created the view.

Comment: Any errors in your recent log messages (watchdog) list?

Comment: Also, if you view the source code in your browser are the times still missing there?

Comment: @rooby: There are no error messages. What do you mean with "view the source code in my browser"?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @rooby: I'm using Firefox's latest version (24.0). I've just checked it: the problem is there in Internet Explorer 10 too.

Comment: In firefox, right click somewhere on the page and then click "View Page Source", then you can use CTRL+F for find and search for the part where your view displays to see if the time is also missing from the html source or if it is just hidden from view via css. You could also try disabling javascript and seeing if the problem persists to eliminate that as a possibility too.

Comment: The page source doesn't provide any information about my dashboard and views. Disabling javascript doesn't work, because I can't access my dashboard anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what causes the problem, but I solved it temporally. I changed the Date format to 'Time ago' an added the 'ago' manually via the 'Rewrite results' function.